# IBM MobileFirst 8.0: JSONStore initialization issue on iOS 13.1

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

My app is working fine on iOS 12.4.1 It already has JSONStore with data inside. After updating to iOS 13.1 Beta 4, I got this error when trying to initialize JSONStore

{\n \"src\": \"initCollection\",\n \"err\": -1,\n \"msg\": \"PERSISTENT_STORE_FAILURE\",\n \"col\": \"globalData\",\n \"usr\": \"common\",\n \"doc\": {},\n \"res\": {}\n}

I've updated cordova-plugin-mfp and cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore yet it's still the same.

This is the code block

> function(collections, successCallback, errorCallback, options) {
>
> ```
>        return WL.JSONStore.init(collections, options)
>            .then(successCallback)
>            .fail(function() {
>                WL.JSONStore.init(collections, options)
>                .then(successCallback).
>                fail(errorCallback);
>            });
> ```
>
> }

Below are the errors in XCode console log

> error 13:43:10.039914 +0800   salesApp    file is not a database in > "select count(*) from sqlite_master;"
>   error 13:43:10.040329 +0800   salesApp    file is not a database in > "create table 'globalData' ( _id INTEGER primary key autoincrement,  > 'globalid' TEXT, json BLOB, _dirty REAL default 0, _deleted INTEGER default 0, _operation TEXT);"
>   error 13:43:11.167875 +0800   salesApp    file is not a database in > "select count(*) from sqlite_master;"
>   error 13:43:11.168313 +0800   salesApp    file is not a database in > "create table 'globalData' ( _id INTEGER primary key autoincrement,  '_id' > REAL, 'globalid' TEXT, json BLOB, _dirty REAL default 0, _deleted > INTEGER default 0, _operation TEXT);"

Really appreciate your feedback, thank you very much..

Comment: Can you share the complete XCode logs of this failure. Also a code snippet that causes this error

Comment: 1>Is it happening after 1st time upgrade to iOS 13? 2> Does it work after killing the app and relaunch? or does it gets stuck in all subsequent launches? 3> Does fresh install app of same app works fine on iOS13?

Comment: 1. Yes it happens after 1st time upgrade to iOS 13
2. Killing app/relaunch, reboot iPad didn't work
3. If install over the existing app, meaning the jsonstore is intact, it won't work. But if delete app and do a fresh install, then it'll work, but all data in jsonstore is lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have sqlite library linked to your project. If yes either remove it or move it down , after sqlcipher.framework in Linking phase of xcode project.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. The root cause is sqlite3 lib caused interference?

Comment: yes.check this https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/important-advisory-sqlcipher-with-xcode-8-and-new-sdks/1688